# App Module Not Found AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

For some reason its giving me errors when i try to run this code. (i will post code then error at bottom):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dist/css/vendor.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" type="text/css" />


    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>


</head>


    <body ng-app="Hive">


      <div ui-view class="main_view">
      </div>


   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-energized">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Discussions" icon="ion-android-contacts" ui-sref="discussions">
          <ion-nav-view name="discussions-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Board" icon="ion-ios-list-outline" ui-sref="board">
          <ion-nav-view name="list-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>


             <ion-tab title="Me" icon="ion-android-happy" ui-sref="me">
          <ion-nav-view name="profile-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>


  </body>


</html>
```

app.module.js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('Hive', [
            'ionic',
            'firebase',
            'ngMaterial'
        ]
    );

});
```

app.route.js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('Hive')
        .config(stateParams)

    /* @ngInject */
    function stateParams($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl:'app/components/home/home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'
            })

            .state('me' , {
                url:'/me',
                templateUrl:'app/components/me/me.html',
                controller:'meCtrl'
            })

            .state('discussions' , {
                url:'/discussions',
                templateUrl:'app/components/discussions/discussions.html',
                controller:'discussionsCtrl'
            })

            .state('board', {
                url:'/board',
                templateUrl:'app/components/board/board.html',
                controller:'boardCtrl'
            })

            .state('register', {
                url:'/register',
                templateUrl:'app/components/register/register.html',
                controller:'registerCtrl'
            })


        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    }
})(angular);
```

I am getting the following errors when i run the code:

```
Error: $injector:nomod
Module Unavailable
Module 'Hive' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module Hive due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/nomod?p0=Hive
    at Error (native)
    at https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:3596
    at https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:10429
    at https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:10940
    at https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:14933
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at o (https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:3925)
    at r (https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:14873)
    at wt (https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:16490)
    at r (https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:9097
```

I dont understand why i am getting these errors at all. I have been debugging for a long time now , but couldnt understand why. Right now im coding all this in website IDE : https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/hive  . Help would be appreciated ! :)

Edit (ngMaterial Not working ^^):
index.html:

```
<head>
    <meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dist/css/vendor.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js"></script>



    <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" type="text/css" />


    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>


</head>


    <body ng-app="Hive">


      <div ui-view class="main_view">
      </div>


   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-energized">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Discussions" icon="ion-android-contacts" ui-sref="discussions">
          <ion-nav-view name="discussions-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Board" icon="ion-ios-list-outline" ui-sref="board">
          <ion-nav-view name="list-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>


             <ion-tab title="Me" icon="ion-android-happy" ui-sref="me">
          <ion-nav-view name="profile-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>


  </body>


</html>
```

app.module.js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('Hive', [
            'ionic',
            'firebase',
            'ngMaterial'
        ]
    );

})(angular);
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing the second parameter to `angular.module`. try `angular.module('Hive', [])`. If you don't pass that array in Angular will try to find an existing module called "Hive" instead of creating a new one

Comment: @rob if you see my code above i do indeed have a parameter with array:  `angular.module('Hive', [
            'ionic',
            'firebase',
            'ngMaterial'
        ]
    );`

Comment: Are you sure that app/*.js files are loaded?

Comment: ah sorry I miss that. Your `app.module.js` code is never being executed though. You wrapped it in a function that is never called

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your `app.module.js` look like this:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('Hive', [
            'ionic',
            'firebase',
            'ngMaterial'
        ]
    );

})(angular);
```

You forgot to pass in the angular object.

Comment: Yea thank a lot! That solved one error that was above but i still have one error left :( . Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=m...)
    at Error (native)
    at https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:3596
    at https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/hive/assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js:3:15261
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at o....  Something wrong with ngMaterial but i cant possibly find whats wrong :(

Comment: You don't seem to have a `script` or `stylesheet` referencing `ngMaterial` in your `<head> ... </head>` tag.

Comment: `ngMaterial` requires multiple Angular libraries than just the base. Check this example: https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.5/getting-started

Comment: Yup exactly^^^. You need to add all the dependencies.

Comment: @austinthedeveloper and 1290 , i copied the exact refrences in material , but still having the same problem. Look at my edit above in question to see the current index.html and app.module.js :(

Comment: @Dsafds What is in your `app.min.js`?

Comment: @1290 thats where all the controllers, ervices, etc.. go on. They get compiled to one file , and minfied

Comment: Hmm okay. Could there be an error in that file? Are you using ng-Material there?

Comment: Try to import the latest files for ngMaterial: https://github.com/angular/material#cdn. Look at the second set of references under that link.

Comment: Yes im using the original Angular-Material. Cant be an error on file because it works on the "Get Started" Page. I even added a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578106/ngmaterial-dependency-not-found

Comment: Just tried that , and didnt work :( . Im currently working this on a Web IDE: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/hive