# ngMaterial dependency not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular-module

For some reason ng-Material is not found in my app , and its giving me errors! Ill show you the code and the error down below:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dist/css/vendor.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js"></script>



    <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" type="text/css" />


    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>


</head>


    <body ng-app="Hive">


      <div ui-view class="main_view">
      </div>


   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-energized">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Discussions" icon="ion-android-contacts" ui-sref="discussions">
          <ion-nav-view name="discussions-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Board" icon="ion-ios-list-outline" ui-sref="board">
          <ion-nav-view name="list-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>


             <ion-tab title="Me" icon="ion-android-happy" ui-sref="me">
          <ion-nav-view name="profile-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>


  </body>


</html>
```

app.module.js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('Hive', [
            'ionic',
            'firebase',
            'ngMaterial'
        ]
    );

})(angular);
```

Errors:

```
vendor.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=Hive&p1=Error%3A%20…sers.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js%3A3%3A14873)
```

As you can see if you click link module ng-Material failed to initatate. I have no idea what this is happening and i also do have the EXACT refs , the Angular Material Get Started Page has: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started  . Help would be very appreciated !! :)

**Edit**

What vendor.min.js is , is that its a library of all my deps i need. It gets all these libraries in paths.js:

```
   'assets/lib/js/ionic/ionic.min.js',
    'assets/lib/js/angular/angular.min.js',
    'assets/lib/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.min.js',
    'assets/lib/js/ionic/ionic-angular.min.js',
    'assets/lib/js/firebase/firebase.js',
    'assets/lib/js/firebase/angularfire.min.js',
```

Puts them all in one file , and then minifies them. I cant see whats the problem there though :( . Im currently working this on a Web IDE Here: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/hive

Comment: There is a problem with your js file **assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js** and the rest of js stop loading because of this error. your detailed error: [link: your detailed error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=Hive&p1=Error:%20…sers.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js:3:14873)

Comment: Thanks @kobe but , i dont really see the error. I edited question to explain what vendor.min.js does and is , on bottom of question

Comment: Some of the angular modules in your vendor.js failed to load

Comment: @kobe Hmm im not sure but error: vendor.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=Hive&p1=Error%3A%20…sers.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js%3A3%3A14873)

Comment: You might need to move vendor.min.js by your app.module.js scripts

Comment: @10100111001 then angular deps like angular-aria messages and so on,wil give errors cause they dont know angular :(